# Why NHibernate create a temporary table when I call the Update method on Query?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I just want to update a column table based on a condition. Here my code :

```cs
this.session.Query<EventEntity>()
     .Where(e => [...])
     .Update(c => new { Enabled = true });
```

This call generates the following SQL :

```sql
insert into HT_event SELECT evententit0_.Id as Id FROM event evententit0_ WHERE [...]
UPDATE event SET Enabled=? WHERE (Id) IN (select Id from HT_event)
```

Why NHibernate creates a temp table to store ids instead of directly generates a correct IN clause ? How can I disable this behavior ?

To give more information, I use a table per class hierarchy inheritance mapping with mapping by code. My `EventEntity` is an abstract class :

```cs
public abstract class EventEntity { ... }

public class EventMap : ClassMapping<EventEntity> { ... }
```

I have a few others entities that inherit from `EventEntity`

```cs
public abstract class MatchEntity { ... }

public class MatchMap : JoinedSubclassMapping<MatchEntity> { ... }
```

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate propose a way to customize the bulk id strategy, but it's not available for NHibernate at this moment : https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2004.